# Slurm jobs not utilizing 100% CPU in parallelisation

Tags: mpi, slurm, abaqus

I'm running an Abaqus job through Slurm with 23 tasks per cpu and 23 cpus with MPI. Using --ntasks=23 The program will after initialization launch 23 processes. The strange behaviour I have is that when checking the CPU usage with 'top' in the terminal it doesn't seem to go above around 5% usage. I want them to have 100%. If I call the abaqus executable directly with the same input parameters, the 23 cpus correctly use 100%.

If I run a job through Abaqus that doesn't launch 23 processes, the CPU usage of one process will go as high as 2000% and perform as expected.

My config looks like this

```
# #
MailProg=/opt/slurm-mail/bin/slurm-spool-mail.py
MpiDefault=none
# #MpiParams=ports=#-#
ProctrackType=proctrack/linuxproc
#ProctrackType=proctrack/cgroup
TaskPlugin=task/cgroup
ReturnToService=1
#FastSchedule=1
# #SlurmctldPort=6817
# #SlurmdPort=6818
#
##Debug
SlurmUser=slurm

SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurmctld.pid
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurmd.pid
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/spool/slurmd
StateSaveLocation=/var/spool/slurmSave
# # SCHEDULING
SchedulerType=sched/builtin
SchedulerParameters=preempt_youngest_first,preempt_strict_order
PriorityType=priority/basic

SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core_Memory,CR_ONE_TASK_PER_CORE
PreemptType=preempt/partition_prio
PreemptMode=suspend,gang
SlurmctldParameters=preempt_send_user_signal

# #
JobSubmitPlugins=lua
# #
# # LOGGING AND ACCOUNTING
AccountingStorageHost=queue
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/slurmdbd
AccountingStorageTRES=gres/license
ClusterName=simulation
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/linux
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurmLog/slurmctld.log
SlurmSchedLogFile=/var/log/slurmLog/slurmsched.log
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurmLog/slurmd.log
JobCompType=jobcomp/filetxt
# # Licenses as generic resources
GresTypes=license
# #
# # COMPUTE NODES
NodeName=nc Sockets=2 CoresPerSocket=12 ThreadsPerCore=1 State=UNKNOWN `RealMemory=257852 Gres=license:abaqus:18`
```

I was not the person who set up our Slurm system, so I'm really just looking for help on what I should look for because I'm not very familiar with it

Edit: I looked at htop instead of top and it appears that instead of using 23 cpus it's starting 23 tasks in one cpu that are all using approximately 4.3% each. Anyone know why it's doing this?

Comment: Does "23 tasks per cpu and 23 cpus with MPI" mean you have 23^2=600 cores? In that case, you need to specify `ntasks=600`. With 23 you get only one MPI process for each of your 23-core nodes. If I understand you correctly.

Comment: Please post your slurm options (e.g. `-N`, `-n` and so on)

Comment: @VictorEijkhout No, sorry for being misleading. This is a bit outside my knowledge area. I have 23 cpus and the program I'm calling seems to launch an MPI process.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Only #SBATCH --ntasks=23 and 
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=0

Comment: so you are running on one node, 23 MPI tasks and no OpenMP, right? Which MPI library are you running? do you use `mpirun` or `srun`? Which SLURM version? IIRC, one SLURM version had an issue with Open MPI and all the MPI tasks ended up on a single core. A workaround is to use `srun` instead of `mpirun`

Comment: I've got slurm version 19.05.2. I'm using neither srun nor mpirun, I'm sending an sbatch with a python script that calls Abaqus. I can't seem to find out what MPI library Abaqus is using, it's not very clear. Best I can see is that it's calling on pmpi.

Comment: Tried executing the routine with srun and 1 task and got the same result. 23 processes on one CPU.

For context, abaqus is called with 23 cpus regardless

Comment: 1. Please don't use the word CPU. Most people understand that to be a processor chip. On the other hand, some utilities call a hardware thread a cpu. Node/socket/core are better terms. 2. Use `ldd` to see what MPI library is linked to your Abaqus executable.

Comment: Using ldd on abaqus returns

        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe6bfdc000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd769a9a000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fd769792000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd76948f000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd769279000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd768eb7000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd769cd1000)

Sorry if this isn't the correct information.
Regardless, cpus=23 is an argument I pass to abaqus

Comment: Are you even sure you are running MPI based Abaqus (and not OpenMP based)? What if you sbatch -n 1 -c 23

Comment: I am not sure. I've just not read anything about abaqus using openMP. 
The logs print this: 
/abaqus/linux86_64/2017/linux_a64/code/bin/SMAExternal/pmpi-9.1.2/bin/mpirun as MPI CMD. 

I tried running with -n 1 -c 23 and got the same issue. 23 tasks on one core

Comment: a quick google says you need to set the `mp_host_list` environment variable before invoking Abaqus with builtin `pmpi`. Did you do that?

Comment: Yes, it's set up as (('nodename, 23),)

Comment: before running abaqus, what does `grep Cpus_allowed_list /proc/self_status` reports? i do not think the syntax is correct (e.g `[` vs `(`). check https://www.pdc.kth.se/software/software/Abaqus/centos7/2018/index_using.html for an example.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I've had the chance to try this now and it made no difference.

Comment: I printed grep Cpus_allowed_list /proc/self/status in the script before Abaqus is called and got

`Cpus_allowed_list: 0-22 `